# Dynamic error style password field accounts-core in Meteor

Tags: meteor, meteorite, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts

I am using [accounts-core](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/blob/master/Guide.md) package in meteor to make my registration form in my application.

I configure own custom validation field in password. i.e.

```
var password = AccountsTemplates.removeField('password');
AccountsTemplates.addField({
    _id: 'password',
    type: 'password',
    required: true,
    displayName: 'Password',
    re: /^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9]).{8,}$/,
    errStr: 'At least 8 characters, 1 uppercase, 1 lowercase and 1 number'
});
```

Now i want to show error message with different style according to what character user missed to type. Something like:

[image]

As per Documentation : [Field Configuration](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/blob/master/Guide.md#form-fields-configuration) we need give **errStr** when field is configured.

And we can write **func** for custom validation:

```
AccountsTemplates.addField({
    ...
    func : function(pwd){
        ...        // check your password
    }
    ...
});
```

But How can i pass dynamic markup to show error message?